# Ace Combat Assault Horizon Fails to Start

Tags: ace-combat-assault-horizon

I can't even start up my AC:AH game. It comes up with a message: "Failed to create Direct3d or games for Windows Live", something like that. I bought the game in store off a disc, and I have tried re-installing and repairing it. FYI, the computer I am running it on does not have a permanent internet connection, but I have tried installing it with internet.

Comment: what are the system specs of your computer? does it meet the minimum requirements for the game? You can run it against [Can You Run It](http://www.systemrequirementslab.com/cyri) to be sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Steps on how to fix this issue**

## Steps:

1. Move mouse pointer over the right-bottom corner of the desktop, the side toolbar will be displayed
2. Click **"Settings"** option
3. Click **"Control Panel"** option
4. In the Control Panel window select **"Remove Program"**
5. In the displayed window double click **"Microsoft Games for Windows - Live Redistributable"** and follow uninstaller instructions.
6. While in "Remove Program" window, double click **"Microsoft Games for Windows Marketplace"** and follow uninstaller instructions.
7. Visit the website:  http://www.xbox.com/LIVE/PC/DownloadClient
8. Download Games for Windows Live Client
9. Run the downloaded installer and follow the displayed instructions
10. After installation is finished game is ready to play

---

## Source

[Ace Combat Direct3D Issue: Microsoft Forums](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-gaming/cannot-play-ace-combat-assault-horizon-game-error/41d50e7e-1bf1-4590-81cc-b917758146dc)

Answer (score 0):

You can and should activate the GFWL CD Key on Steam which gets rid of GFWL completely and replaces it with Steamworks. If you don't have or know what Steam is, you can get the free client [here](http://store.steampowered.com/about). Via Steamworks, you are also able to use the multi player again, since it is dead if you play via GFWL.

[GFWL was removed from Ace Combat a few months ago](http://www.pcgamer.com/ace-combat-assault-horizon-calls-an-air-strike-on-games-for-windows-live/), in anticipation of Microsoft abandoning Games for Windows Live.

Activating it on Steam will also get rid of your problem. However, you will need an internet connection to activate and download the game, since the disc version is not aware of Steam.

Comment: Will I have to download the game from steam, instead of using the installed data from the disc? Thanks

Comment: @PlanetAlexander You can try to feed the data from the disc after it is installed to steam by copying the game into the folder where it downloads it. It should recognize most of the data. The folder would be `Steam\SteamApps\downloading\228400`. Initiate the download, exit Steam (via the menu, otherwise it runs in the background), copy the files there, relaunch Steam. Then it should recognize most of the files. Of course, you will have to download necessary patches, but the download should be much smaller. No guarantee though.